# How to prove this set of elements has or $0$ or infinite elements

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U= \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Im}(z) >0\}$ and $\overline{U}= \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Im}(z) \geq0\}$

Let $C(\overline{U},\mathbb{R})$ be the set of continuous functions from $\overline{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

and $g$ a continuous function define as following $g: \overline{U} \setminus U = \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I have to prove that the following set $X = \{ u \in  C(\overline{U},\mathbb{R}) : u\restriction_{U} \text{harmonic  and } u\restriction_{\mathbb{R}} = g \}$ has either $0$ or infinite elements.

I see this related question: [How to prove this set of functions has only one element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706826/how-to-prove-this-set-of-functions-has-only-one-element)

But I do not really see the difference why in that case it is proven that the set has only one element and in my case it has infinite (or $0$)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$ \{\, u \in  C(\overline{U},\mathbb{R}) : u\restriction_{U} \text{ harmonic}\,\}$ and $C(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$ are vector spaces and $u\mapsto u\restriction_{\Bbb R}$ is a linear map.

---

More down to earth:

a) Can you name infinitely many such $u$ when $g$ is the constant $0$ function?

b) If $u$ is one solution for a given $g$, how can you use a) to obtain infinitely many?